# Passing anonymous function to custom event trigger in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback, anonymous-function, jquery-callback, custom-events

I'm trying to trigger custom events on DOM elements and pass anonymous functions to be executed when the event is triggered (using jQuery). So something like this:

```
$(some-dom).live("custom_event", function(evtObj, data, callback) {
//do some stuff
callback();
});

$(some-button).click(function() {
    $(some-dom).trigger("custom_event", some_data, function () {
        alert("this is my anonymous function passed as event data");
    }
});
```

So clicking on "some-button" should trigger "custom_event" on "some-dom" and cause the anonymous function that I passed on the trigger to be executed. Right? But the browser says that callback is undefined in the custom event. Am I doing something wrong? Is passing anonymous functions as trigger arguments not allowed? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass multiple extra arguments to `trigger()` as an Array. *(One argument can be passed without the Array.)*

```
$(some-dom).click(function() {      //  v-----pass extra args in an Array
    $(some-dom).trigger("custom_event", [some_data, function () {
        alert("this is my anonymous function passed as event data");
    }]);
 //  ^------Array
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NRSJ2/

Comment: Right you are! How did I miss that! Thanks :)

Comment: @Jayraj & @user113716 I am doing the same as shown in answer but I get error on console as `NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO: 
alert("this is my anonymous function passed as event data");` Why? I only changed that I have used `on` instead of `live` to register custom event

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing some sample code. Maybe you could try creating a new question? Also, given that this answer is over 4 years old, it's possible that there have been API changes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#testelement').live("test_event", function(e, myCallback) {
    myCallback();
});

$('#clickme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var myFunc = function () {
        alert("this is my anonymous function passed as event data");
    };

    $('#testelement').trigger('test_event', [myFunc]);
});
```

Here is the [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mJ4rp/).

Comment: Well yes, using a named function would work too. I wanted to use an anonymous function for terseness but didn't realize I had to pass arguments in an array. Thanks. :)